# REST API Request constantly returning HTML instead of JSON

Tags: c#, json, api, rest

For the last few hours, I've been trying to write a separate project for consuming an API. Documentation/examples for it are [here](http://docs.payu21.apiary.io/#reference/api-endpoints/paymethods-api-endpoint/create-a-new-order).

Sadly, I can't get an "application/json" response from it, even with example values from documentation. Here's the code for my method with example values (which is copy/pasted from the documentation). I've tried a few modifications but I don't even know where to start digging.

```
public async void SendOrder()
{
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = baseAddress })
    {

        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("authorization", "Bearer 3e5cac39-7e38-4139-8fd6-30adc06a61bd");
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        using (var content = new StringContent("{  \"notifyUrl\": \"https://your.eshop.com/notify\",  \"customerIp\": \"127.0.0.1\",  \"merchantPosId\": \"145227\",  \"description\": \"RTV market\",  \"currencyCode\": \"PLN\",  \"totalAmount\": \"21000\",  \"products\": [    {      \"name\": \"Wireless mouse\",      \"unitPrice\": \"15000\",      \"quantity\": \"1\"    },    {      \"name\": \"HDMI cable\",      \"unitPrice\": \"6000\",      \"quantity\": \"1\"    }  ]}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
        {

            using (var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("api/v2_1/orders/", content/*, null, "application/json"*/))
            {
                string responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*responseData* value - http://pastebin.com/t3EYyP8w

Comment: Check the response Code and Content, it will tell you the problem (unauthorized, bad request, not found, etc).

Comment: can you post responseData value?

Comment: Edited post with pastebin link containing responseData value.
Response code is 200 and its content is what I should get, only issue is response type which should be "application/json" just like in the examples from documentation.

Answer (score -1):

I would give RestSharp a try, can install it via Nuget. Has a easy way of doing it. http://restsharp.org/

```
var client = new RestClient("https://Whatever.com/api/");
client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("Bearer", "YourToken");

//Add the Method you are executing from API
var request = new RestRequest("resource/{id}", Method.POST);

//Add your paramers like this
request.AddParameter("name", "value"); 

//Json
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

//Execute Post
var response = client.execute(request);

//If you want to turn Json into Model
var responseModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourObject>(response.Content);
```

Comment: I've tried using RestSharp, adding "Accept" Header to request but still, response Content-Type is "text/html".

Comment: @Dylan What is the problem you see in the question that RestSharp  can solve?